# Wpf DispatcherTimer.Tick interupted by mouse hook event in same thread

Tags: wpf, dispatchertimer

I have a created a thread that has a dispatcher run for processing low level mouse hook events, and created a DispatcherTimer based on this dispatcher.

When DispatcherTimer.Tick() was fired, I simulated another mouse down message. Then something strange happend:
The Dispatcher.Tick() was interupted and mouse hook event fired in the **same thread**. After the mouse hook event processed, the DispatcherTimer.Tick() continues to end.

From what I understand, the dispatcher will process tasks one by one, so it should execute the DispatcherTimer.Tick() method completely, then other hook events.

Is this behaivor normal?
Is there anyway that I can ensure DispatcherTimer.Tick() was executed completely before hook event fired?

---

Creating dispatcher thread:

```
public static class DispatcherBuilder 
    {
        public static Dispatcher Build()
        {
            Dispatcher dispatcher = null;
            var manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            var thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
                var synchronizationContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext(dispatcher);
                SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(synchronizationContext);

                manualResetEvent.Set();

                try
                {
                    Dispatcher.Run();
                }
                catch 
                {
                    // ignore
                }
            }, maxStackSize:1);
            thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal;
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
            manualResetEvent.WaitOne();
            manualResetEvent.Dispose();
            return dispatcher;
        }
    }
```

Code for creating timer and hook setup:

```
// creating disapatcher:

            _hookDispatcher = DispatcherBuilder.Build();




// creating timer on the dispatcher
            _mouseDownTimer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, _hookDispatcher);
            _mouseDownTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(mouseDownTimer_Tick);
            _mouseDownTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(_dataService.Settings.RightBtnPopupDelayMs);



// create hook

            _hookDispatcher.Invoke(() =>
            {
                _mouseHook = new MouseHook();

                _mouseHook.MouseUp += MouseHookOnMouseUp;
                _mouseHook.MouseDown += MouseHookOnMouseDown;
                _mouseHook.MouseWheel += MouseHookOnMouseWheel;
                _mouseHook.MouseMove += MouseHookOnMouseMove;
                _mouseHook.MouseHWheel += MouseHookOnMouseHWheel;

                _mouseHook.Start();
            });
```

The following is some Debug.WriteLine() output:

```
177,250 MouseDown  Right Thread:14
177,250 MouseDown Right Captured Thread:14

// DeispatcherTimer.Tick() Started
177,360  Timer  Tick  Begin  Thread:14   -- in DeispatcherTimer.Tick()
177,360  Sending RightButtonDown  -- in DeispatcherTimer.Tick()

// MouseHookOnMouseUp() called in same thread
177,485 MouseUp  Right Thread:14  -- in MouseHookOnMouseUp()
177,500 MouseUp Right Captured Thread:14 -- in MouseHookOnMouseUp()

// MouseHookOnMouseDown() called in same thread
177,500 MouseDown  Right Thread:14  -- in MouseHookOnMouseDown()

// Returned to DeispatcherTimer.Tick() in same thread
177,500  Timer Tick End -- in DeispatcherTimer.Tick()


177,500 MouseDown  Right Thread:14
```

Comment: Can you share a code sample?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I'v add some code, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be alright.

> "When DispatcherTimer.Tick() was fired, I simulated another mouse down
>   message. Then something strange happend: The Dispatcher.Tick() was
>   interupted and mouse hook event fired in the same thread. [...]"

In general event handlers are executed on the same thread the event was raised on, except execution is marshalled to a different thread by the event source or the handler itself.
Since you had explicitly setup the `DispatcherTimer` to run on the `_hookDispatcher`, the `Tick` handler, which raises the event, runs on the `_hookDispatcher` thread. Therefore the `Tick` handler and all events raised by this handler and their corresponding event handlers execute on the same thread - the thread the `DispatcherTimer` is associated with.

This answers your first question, why the event handlers are executed on the same thread the `DispatcherTimer` executes on.

> "[...] After the mouse hook event processed, the
>   DispatcherTimer.Tick() continues to end.
>
> From what I understand, the dispatcher will process tasks one by one,
>   so it should execute the DispatcherTimer.Tick() method completely,
>   then other hook events."

Events are always raised *synchronously* (WPF doesn't implement asynchronous events).

1) The `Tick` handler will execute.
2) This handler raises a mouse event.
3) The event delegate is invoked *synchronously*, which means the continuation of the `Tick` handler is "suspended".
4) Invocation of the mouse event delegate means all registered callbacks are invoked too.
5)  After the last callback was invoked the `Tick` handler can continue execution.

So your observations are correct, but this behavior is absolutely normal in this context.

If you want the `Tick` handler continue to execute while the mouse event will be handled, you should raise the mouse event on a background thread. But since input events are handled to do UI related work, it is very likely that those handlers will invoke the `Dispatcher` to access UI resources (or any `DispatcherObject`). Executing such handlers on a background thread, forcing the handlers to synchronize with the UI thread again is too expensive and usually doesn't make any sense.

The recommended solution is to raise the events using `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync`:

```
private void OnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(RaiseMouseEvent, DispatcherPriority.Background);
}
```

`Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` executes asynchronous. Therefore, control returns immediately to the calling object (the `Tick` handler) after it is called.